# Alphabatic Anagrams doesn't work with words that contains letters with multiple occurence

Tags: python, brute-force

Hello how are you? I have a challenge https://www.codewars.com/kata/53e57dada0cb0400ba000688/solutions/python and I've stuck on it for a 2 days, I created the first solution but it was slow(using itertools.permutations), and then I've make this block of code.

```py
import math

def listPosition(word):
    n = 0
    wlsort = list(word)
    wlsort.sort()
    wcopy = word
    
    while wcopy:
        for i in range(wlsort.index(wcopy[0])):
            n += math.factorial(len(wlsort) - 1)
        wlsort.pop(wlsort.index(wcopy[0]))
        wcopy = wcopy[1:]
    return n + 1
```

but it doesn't work with words like `test` `bookkeeper`, Do you have any hints, or idea on how to solve it?

I think my problem is that when I have a word like `car` it will brute-force it like ->
`acr`, `arc`...
and if i have `caar` it will brute-force it like ->
`aacr`, `aarc` and it doesn't do `acar` because it is brute-forcing alphabetically.

Comment: Try to read and compare my approach and see if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. It's quite straightforward, if you read the req. carefully.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
from math import factorial as fact 
def listPosition(word):
    count = 0
    while len(word):
        first = word[0]
        uniqs = set(word)
        possibles = fact(len(word))
        
        for ch in uniqs:
            possibles /= fact(word.count(ch))
            
        for ch in uniqs:
            if ch < first: 
                count += possibles/len(word) * word.count(ch)
        word = word[1:]
        
    return count + 1
```